# Plot a smooth curve for an array and a normal one for another - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have the following to plot, two arrays of shapes (120,) and (120,). For the second array, I am trying to get a smooth plot, but unable to do so.
The following plots a normal plot:

```
 add_z = array([ 22.39409055, 20.91765398, 19.80805759, 19.14836638, 23.54310977, 19.68638808, 21.25143616, 21.32550146, 18.80392599, 17.37016759, 19.21143494, 18.27464661, 21.25150385, 20.61853909 ]) 

 dataNew = array([[ 26.69], [ 24.94], [ 22.37], [ 23.5 ], [ 22.69], [ 22.62], [ 18.5 ], [ 20.87], [ 19. ], [ 19.75], [ 20.72], [ 19.78], [ 20.38], [ 22.06]])

 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 plt.figure(figsize = (10,5))
 plt.plot(dataNew[:],'g')
 plt.plot(add_z[:],'b');
```

I tried using `scipy's` interpolation methods but, I am really not familiar with splines. I am trying to get `dataNew` as a normal plot and `add_z` as a smooth curve to go along in the same plot window. Both are `numpy` arrays.

Comment: Egzamples of `dataNew` and `add_z` would be useful.

Comment: @Marcin: `add_z = array([ 22.39409055,  20.91765398,  19.80805759,  19.14836638,   23.54310977,  19.68638808,  21.25143616,  21.32550146............18.80392599,  17.37016759,  19.21143494,  18.27464661,  21.25150385,  20.61853909,  22.89028155,  22.3965408 ])` and `dataNew = array([[ 26.69],  [ 24.94],  [ 22.37], [ 23.5 ],  [ 22.69],  [ 22.62]....[ 18.5 ],  [ 20.87], [ 19.  ],  [ 19.75], [ 20.72],      [ 19.78],  [ 20.38],  [ 22.06]])` . Thanks

Comment: The ellipses in those arrays mean this still isn't copy-paste-runnable; please edit them (maybe to truncated versions) in the post, theseeker1.

Comment: @cphlewis : Done the same.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "smooth"?  Do you mean you actually want to run a smoothing kernel over the data, or do you mean you want to interpolate it somehow?  If the latter, you don't specify enough info ... to what new grid do you want to interpolate?

Answer (score 2):

This is just patching on another stackoverflow answer which I have embarassingly misplaced:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

add_z = np.array([ 22.39409055, 20.91765398, 19.80805759, 19.14836638, 23.54310977, 19.68638808, 21.25143616, 21.32550146, 18.80392599, 17.37016759, 19.21143494, 18.27464661, 21.25150385, 20.61853909, 22.89028155, 22.3965408 ])

dataNew = np.array([[ 26.69], [ 24.94], [ 22.37], [ 23.5 ], [ 22.69], [ 22.62], [ 18.5 ], [ 20.87], [ 19. ], [ 19.75], [ 20.72], [ 19.78], [ 20.38], [ 22.06]])

plt.figure(figsize = (10,5))
plt.plot(dataNew[:],'g')
plt.plot(add_z[:],'b');

from scipy import interpolate
f = interpolate.interp1d(np.arange(len(add_z)), add_z, kind='cubic')
xnew = np.arange(0, len(add_z)-1, 0.1)
ynew = f(xnew)
plt.plot(xnew, ynew, 'b:')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried it out, but am only add_z is getting displayed. As mentioned, they are (120,) arrays.

Comment: Unclear comment. Note that in this code only add_z is being passed to `interpolate`, if you want another array interpolated you can edit the code. Also, you can compare the shape of the arrays in this code and the shape of your original arrays and transpose or reshape as needed.

Comment: Hey, @thes, how'd that do?